# What affects the curl response time?

Tags: curl

I have a certain curl request that takes almost 2 minutes to provide a response.
Checking further I see that the response is quite large (it returns a number of unique rows).

```
curl http://192.168.220.122:7071/abc | wc -l
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8831k  100 8831k    0     0  75917      0  0:01:59  0:01:59 --:--:-- 2213k
79800
```

Is it safe to conclude that the response time depends on the amount of data in the response? I tried to check different sources, but am unable to find sources that say so.
Thanks for your help in advance!